# Angular2 checkbox to enable button in ngFor

Tags: angular

My problem will for sure seems very simple for some people but I struggle finding a simple solution to achieve this:

- In a ngFor loop, I display some items ID and date. On each item i want to add a delete button.
- This button is disabled by default and only activated if I tick a checkbox (as a confirmation for deletion).

Here is my code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemsArray ">
    <td>{{item .date | date:'short'}}</td>
    <td>{{item .id}}</td>
    <td>Delete?
      Yes, Sure: <input type="checkbox">
      <br>
      <button [disabled]="" (click)="delete(item .id")></button>
    </td>
<tr>
```

On app.component.ts, there is only one variable to go through:

```
const itemsArray = [
    {id: 1, date: 1488170777813},
    {id: 2, date: 1488170777813},
    {id: 5, date: 1488170777813},
    {id: 3, date: 1488170777813},
    {id: 4, date: 1488170777813}
];
```

Delete function is just a `http.delete()` to remote API.

My question is: how ton bind the checkbox with disable state of my button since i'm inside a loop?

Comment: Post your whole code, with `itemsArray` variable, etc.

Comment: I just added some more information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add one more field in itemsArray as

```
const itemsArray = [
    {id: 1, date: 1488170777813, disabled: true},
    {id: 2, date: 1488170777813, disabled: true},
    {id: 5, date: 1488170777813, disabled: true},
    {id: 3, date: 1488170777813, disabled: true},
    {id: 4, date: 1488170777813, disabled: true}
];
```

And then in your template u can use as

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemsArray">
    <td>{{item.date | date:'short'}}</td>
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>Delete?
      Yes, Sure: <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.disabled" checked="!item.disabled">
      <br>
      <button [disabled]="item.disabled" (click)="delete(item.id")></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's a nice idea but it lead to change my data model after having got it from http request.

Comment: yes but I didn't find any other way to do that.because we need to track which checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Since we sre inside a ngfor do you think we could be able to use index to buils reference on the go? I dont know how we can add index to create for example an attribute such #checkbox{$index} and then check the value inside the [disabled]?